# Is it possible to extend IRI to answer to an HTTP GET?

Tags: iri-node, ixi

There are some use cases where the distributed ledger is extremely useful to store security information in a decentralized storage. But those information need to be pulled out from the tangle by a web page that is stored on a web server that is a centralized entity.

It like my IOTA node (and others) to answer to a browser asking IOTA_NODE/txID with a HTML page that is stored in a TX (or bundle).

The page will interact with the user and extract the required data from the tangle.

Every IOTA nodes could answer alternatively creating distributed front end platform.

I've texted IXI module extension but it seems it support only POST while the web browser use the GET HTTP.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This might be a good use case for installing a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx) in front of the IRI node.  It can forward all POST requests directly to the node, while routing GET requests through a different application.  Putting a reverse proxy in front of the node also empowers you to implement rate limiting, caching, and other measures, as well as potentially protecting you from being hacked in the event that a security vulnerability is discovered in the IRI codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There is something called IXI. It is not standardized yet. So, you should not use it for production apps. You can take a look into the [MAM IXI module](https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM.ixi) to get an idea how this works. It is basiclly just Javascript which will be executed within the [JavaX script engine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html). So, it is possible to use the internal Java objects in a Javascript IXI module.

Comment: Thanks Citrullin. Unfortunately the code that manage the HTTP request (API.java) do not manage the GET requests. So even a if one can write am IXI module to mange the request, it will never called by a HTTP GET. Me and my team are working to fix this and submit a pull request to the dev team.